# ShareActivityProvider does not show up as a button

Tags: java, android, action, share

My ShareActionProvider does not show an icon.  My app crashes if I showAsAction. It does provide a share action, I just want it to show a button with an icon instead of the word, and I want to set showAsAction to "always." My inflate code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"                                    
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:context=".MainActivity"
style="@style/AppTheme">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="? 
 attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"   
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For the menu, my XML is here.  I'm using the v7 compatibility library.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"    
android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:title="Share"
    app:actionProviderClass="support.v7.android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Crashes here if menu_item_share.showAsAction == "always":   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your menu with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"    
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never"
       />
     <item
         android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
         android:title="Share"
         app:actionProviderClass="support.v7.android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
         android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
         app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Changes - Add icon to share and change `showAsAction` to `ifRoom`

Cheers, 
Sha

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)